# How to get the rows of a product stocks data in which the running quantities reaches the specified limit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the **recent** purchased items by supplying the quantity it can reach.

Ex. quantity limit: 15

**Data**

```
ID ITEM QTY *RUNNING QTY*
-- ---- --- -----------
1  itemA 20 *41*
2  itemB 10 *21* --the limit **15** is up to this rows starting at the bottom (recent purchased items)
3  itemA  5 *11*
4  itemA  6 *6*
```

**the result would be:**

```
ID ITEM  QTY
- ----- ---
2 itemB 10
3 itemA  5 
4 itemA  6
```

Another example:
quantity limit: 8

**Data**

```
ID ITEM  QTY
- ----- ---
1 itemA 20
2 itemB 10 
3 itemA  5 ---8
4 itemA  6
```

**the result would be:**

```
ID ITEM  QTY
- ----- ---
3 itemA  5 
4 itemA  6
```

Comment: Well,what have you tried so far?

Comment: You've told us what you want, but what is your question? What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? You have enough reputation to know how to ask a good question. Sample data and expected results will be needed in addition to your attempt(s)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you will understand the question based on the sample data and expected result that i presented.

Comment: What question, @h3n? You haven't asked one; all you did was made a statement on what you need (that isn't a question). Why is the expected value `15`, but that value isn't in your expected results? You haven't explained anything, or shown your efforts; making this an impossible statement to respond to other than my asking you questions.

Comment: the value 15 is not the expected result but the expected result (3 rows) as shown from the description.

Comment: Adding another example does not make a question; you still need to ask a question. "I need" isn't a question. How do you answer the 'question' "I need a new car."? You can't, because it isn't a question. Help us help you by giving us a question we can answer, explain your logic, and show your attempts.

Comment: @larnu, sorry if you have difficulty understanding the question. I thought the example data would make it easier for you to understand what I needed. I updated the question and description.

Comment: This question should be re-opened and upvoted.  It is actually pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (order by id) desc as running_qty
      from t
     ) t
where running_qty - qty < 15;
```

You seem to want the first row that *exceeds* 15, so the quantity in the given row is subtracted from the cumulative sum.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. You understood my question and examples and you gave your answer.